# I want to subscribe to flashloan events on the Aave v2 contract via websocket, how do I find the function/event?

Tags: etherscan, abi, flash-loans, websocket, aave

I am trying to set up a websocket connection with ethers.js to listen for flashloan events.

I have made a connection successfully listening to Transfer events on the USDT contract - which was simple because the 'Transfer' event was there to see in the contract tab on Etherscan.io.

For the Aave contract, there appears to be 6 files of contracts, however none of them mention flashloans or anything that seems related.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9#code

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the proxy contract.

in etherscan go to "Contract" -> "Read as Proxy" and then go to proxy implementation. currently it is pointing here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x085e34722e04567df9e6d2c32e82fd74f3342e79#code

and here you see the `flashLoan` function and abi.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you